# Saving XMPPMessage in CoreData in XMPPFrameWork ios

Tags: ios, save, message, xmppframework

I am working on a chat application and using xmppframework .Now there is a need for storing message in a persistent storage. Can anyone tell me how can i store and retrieve message from CoreData in IOS.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using github/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework, it's easy to get both your incoming and outgoing message stored during initializing:

```
//this code init your XMPPStream
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppStream.autoStartTLS = YES;

xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc]init];
[xmppReconnect activate:self.xmppStream];

xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc]initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];    //By this line all your messages are stored in CoreData
[xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

To retrieve the saved message, here's the sample code in my project:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

fetchRequest.entity = messageEntity;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
//Now you get the NSArray with element type of "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
```

Comment: hi AdrianHou ... actually i am receving the message in - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message... now here onwards how to save my messages in XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage ...

Comment: I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject'' Please help to debug this exception

Comment: Hello @Adrian , How can I do same for MUC?

Comment: Hello @AdrianHou, I am using your code,but this is not working.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework 
If yes then it by defaults implements core data and you just have to make minor changes to get the chat message...

Comment: yes i am using this link. How can i store message in data base. Please tell me.

Comment: There is XMPPMessageArchiving model .. study this .. Message first gets store into that.. and user can fetch the data from the this ...